# MySql selecting last 10 rows without disturbing the order

Tags: mysql

I want to select the last 10 rows but the order should remain the asc only.

Its like displaying the last page in a forum but the post are still aligned in the right order.

I tried to do this

```
SELECT users.display,appreply.*,users.userid,users.avtar FROM appreply
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.userid=appreply.userid
    WHERE appreply.appid='$appid'
    ORDER by apprepid DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

But as i said this disturbs the order. 
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT X.* FROM
(
SELECT users.display,a.apprepid apprepid_ar, a.appid appid_ar, a.reply reply_ar, a.userid userid_ar, a.browser browser_ar, a.os os_ar, a.time time_ar,users.userid,users.avtar FROM appreply a
LEFT JOIN users ON users.userid=a.userid
WHERE a.appid='$appid'
ORDER by a.apprepid DESC
LIMIT 10
) X ORDER BY X.apprepid_ar ASC
```

Comment: Error : Every Derived table must have its own alias

Comment: this happens only because some column(s) in `appreply` and `users` are named the same... please provide all column names... then the query can be changed accordingly...

Comment: k wait. U want all the columns for both tables `users` and `appreply` rt ?

Comment: appreply: apprepid , appid , reply , userid , browser , os , time.  users : userid , display , avtar , username , password , powers , verified , regcode.

Comment: what do you mean by "complicated" ? MySQL needs to have unique column names when using "subquery"... I just used your query as a subquery and told MySQL to change the order of the result of your query...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3355/discussion-between-kritya-and-yahia)

Answer (score -1):

You might be having an auto-increment field in the table, which is usually 'Id'.
Instead of using the DESC operator on the apprepid field, use the Id field as:

```
SELECT users.display,appreply.*,users.userid,users.avtar FROM appreply
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.userid=appreply.userid
    WHERE appreply.appid='$appid'
    **ORDER by id DESC**
    LIMIT 10 ORDER BY apprepid ASC
```

Comment: What did u changed ? :O Can u explain please ? Thanks

Comment: The changed part in on the 4th lne. The line is highlighted with stars. I changed the field 'apprepid' to 'id'. There must a default auto-increment field in your table as 'Id'. Sorry for inconvenience